# select resultset of two tables without merging result

Tags: sql

I have a question if this is possible.

```
Table a     Table b 
-------     --------
test1       test4
test2       test5
test3


result
------------------
test1      test4
test2      test5
test3
```

like a temporary table but from two tables.
When you try to select this columns like a normal select statement they are combining the result.
But what i want is that the even dont know each other just get display in columns side by side.
what i logically want is 
 
select (select column from table a, select column from table b)from dual

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you do not have any relation between the tables? What RDMS are you using? (Mysql,oracel,MSSQL)

Comment: Are the individual columns ordered, or is that just a coincidence of the sample data? And you must tell us the database type

Comment: there is no relation between them. i just need the result in one resultset that i could display them in one Report in Apex.
Its Oracle i use. They arent ordered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, assuming that you have an `id` in each table to specify the ordering.  SQL tables represent unordered sets.

Here is a method that should work in most databases, including Oracle:

```
select t1.col1 as cola, t2.col1 as colb
from (select t1.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum from table1 t1) t1 full outer join
     (select t2.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum from table2 t2) t2
     on t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```